# Spinner Mode does not work

Tags: android, android-widget, android-spinner

I have two spinner, one with

```
android:spinnerMode="dialog"
```

and another with

```
android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
```

Now when I click on either spinner, I find no difference between them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8231086/1168654 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/12632633/1168654

Comment: Post some more code for better understanding

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: mode_dialog][image: mode_dropdown]This is strange. When adding 
android:prompt="@string/app_name"
It shows a little difference in dialog and dropdown style. Otherwise both are almost the same. Try using properties for dropdown and dialog to differentiate between the two.

Comment: if I set prompt to both spinner than their is no difference